# jquery - serializeArray for form

Tags: jquery

Can i do serializeArray for form like this -
?

```
$(document).on("click", ".rq-submit", function(e){  
    var formData = $(this).parents("form").serializeArray();

    formData.push({name: 'act', value: act});
    formData.push({name: 'rqID', value: rqID});
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="rq-form-2" action="#"  method="post"  class="rq-form ">
    <input type="text" name="rq[name]">
    <input type="text" name="rq[email]">
    <input class="btn btn-success rq-submit" data-act="edit" value="SUBMIT" type="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: Fix extra `(` and should work. What problem are you having when you try? Note you need to prevent the default submit button action

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Sure you removed the extra `(` but provided no additional insight into a specific problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send url-encoded form data which is ajax default content Type and also how browser sends form you could use `serialize()` and `$.param()` which serializes an object

```js
$(document).on("submit", ".rq-form", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    var extraParams ={
      act:22,
      rqId:44
    }
    
    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    var postData = formData +'&'+ $.param(extraParams);
    
    console.log(postData);
   
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="rq-form-2" action="#"  method="post"  class="rq-form ">
    <input type="text" name="rq[name]" value="foo">
    <input type="text" name="rq[email]" value="bar">
    <input class="btn btn-success rq-submit" data-act="edit" value="SUBMIT" type="submit" >
</form>
```